# Having trouble understanding this function return

Tags: c, tree, return, void

I am working with the following code I found on here to begin my project that involves a tree data structure.

```
struct node{

    int ID;
    struct node* next;
    struct node* child;
};

typedef struct node node;

node* new_node(int);
node* add_sibling(node*, int);
node* add_child(node*, int);


int main()
{
    int i;
    node *root = new_node(0);
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        add_child(root, i);
}

node * new_node(int ID)
{
    node* new_node =(node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (new_node) {
        new_node->next = NULL;
        new_node->child = NULL;
        new_node->ID = ID;
    }

    return new_node;
}

node* add_sibling(node* n, int ID)
{
    if (n == NULL)
        return NULL;

    while (n->next)
        n = n->next;

    return (n->next = new_node(ID));
}

node* add_child(node* n, int ID)
{
    if (n == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (n->child)
        return add_sibling(n->child, ID);
    else
        return (n->child = new_node(ID));
}
```

I am a beginner with C/C++ and programming in general. I think I understand everything about the code except for the *add_child* function. The function seems to return a pointer to a node, but when it is called in main, it seems to be called as though it were a void function. I would have thought to call the function this way

```
*root = add_child(root,i);
```

like how new_node is called, or to write add_child as a void function, but both of these modifications results in errors (not to mention the implementation in the code I found *does* work). What am I missing?

Comment: You can call a method that return a value and just not use the returned value. Which is what your main is doing.

Comment: Is there a reason you think the author wrote it this way?

Comment: Because he did not need to use the return value at all in the main, but it could be usefull in other circumstances

Comment: I understand, thank you. I see I can change it to a void function and get the same results (in the case where I am not needing the return value).

Answer (score 0):

This function rewritten will look like following.

```
node* add_child(node* n, int ID)
{
    // For null pointer return null
    if (n == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    // If element has child add a sibling to that child
    if (n->child)
    {
        node* sibling_for_child = add_sibling(n->child, ID);
        return sibling_for_child;
    }
    else
    {
        // Otherwise just add element as a child
        node* child_node = new_node(ID);
        n->child = child_node;
        return child_node;
    }
}
```

The result of assignment is an assigned value(*) like in this chaining assignment:

```
int a, b;
a = b = 3;
```

which is actually:

```
a = (b = 3);
```

or

```
b = 3;
a = b;
```

Comment: Thanks, the way you've rewritten the code is much clearer and I will use it. My confusion, though, stemmed from the return of the function not being used, but the commenter above cleared that up for me.

Comment: How does this address the OP's concern: "but when it is called in main, it seems to be called as though it were a void function"?

Comment: It does not. This answer is more about "I think I understand everything about the code except for the add_child function"